# Flag reason for "I have answered your question" comments on questions?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

What's the best flag reason for comments on questions of the form "I have answered your question"?

Comment: IMO: _not constructive_.

Comment: Another option is just to ignore them.  It is just noise, and the chances are that the offender won't even notice that his noisy comment has been deleted.  So your effort and the moderator's effort will be wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"not constructive", "obsolete" and "too chatty" all apply. I suppose you can just pick the one you like best, or the one that fits the tone or the motivation of the comment best. If an asker has verbally acknowledged the comment, flagging both comments as "obsolete" is a no-brainer.

If you have a feeling that none of the canned options makes it obvious that "I have answered your question" comments are straight-up unnecessary and that a mod might decline and ignore your flag (I mean, that's what everybody seems to be afraid of these days), I suppose you'll just have to spell it out in a custom flag. I know a comment of this kind when I see one and am more than eager to delete on sight, but I've never been the dedicated comment flag handler — my specialty lies elsewhere...